# Rails - how to handle routes that don't exist ("No route matches [GET]")?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

My `route` looks like

```
match 'about' => 'company#about'
```

When I set to the url `http://localhost:3000/aboutttt`, I get the error message

```
No route matches [GET] "/aboutttt"
```

I want to give the user better feedback than that.

The best solution by my opinion could be redirect the app back, or on the homepage of the app, but exist in routes any way to set default route, when I get the error above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run your app with the environment set to production and I think you'll find you'll no longer see this message. It's a convenience for debugging while you're developing.

There's a setting in `config/environments/production.rb` or `config/environments/development.rb` (I can't remember which way round) which controls whether exceptions are rendered as views. This is off for production - instead you get the 404.html that's in `public`, which you can change as you please.

Comment: I know I can modify the `public/404.html` as I want, but in this case - the solution for my question would be put `= render :template => 'home/index'` into the `public/404.html`. But to be honest, this is not very clear solution...

Comment: I see, I missed that part of you question. In my opinion you need to let the user know they've typed an incorrect URL rather than just redirecting them to home, which could be confusing for them, especially if they keep repeatedly trying to use an incorrect bookmark for example.

Comment: Have you tried my solution of `match '*a' => redirect("/")` at the bottom of your routes?

Comment: @Russell well, users mostly doesn't type the URL address, but clicking the links and the links are correct. The bad URL address is caused usually by the people who are trying to see what happend, if they set a bad URL. But I agree, just to display the `404.html` page is the fastest solution

Comment: @Robin well, `match '*a' => redirect("/")` solving only `http://localhost:3000/aboutttt`, but already not eg. `http://localhost:3000/articles/newwww`

Comment: It's the fastest and it's the standard, right across the internet. Go with the standard!

Comment: But it would solve `http://localhost:3000/resources_that_does_not_exist/newwww` I think. It's because `http://localhost:3000/articles/newwww` is not the same "error" than the first one, is it? It's a missing action, and there is other ways to deal with that.

Answer (score 7):

While you are on development. Make changes inside config/environments/development.rb by setting: 
`config.consider_all_requests_local = false`

This will disable full error reporting and instead shows a page with interactive response for users. But this is already disabled on production environment. But I don't recommend turning it off in development mode.