# Rails - handle exceptions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I know how to handle error which RecordNotFound

But how can I handle Routing Error (No route matches [GET])?

PS in this topic I don't find an answer - [Rails - how to handle routes that don't exist ("No route matches [GET]")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218912/rails-how-to-handle-routes-that-dont-exist-no-route-matches-get)

Comment: I feel that you should fix routing errors by changing the routes or changing the controller or view calls that are using them, e.g. for paths.  I would focus on and post that code in a different question (or redo this one), as opposed to 'handling' the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After every other route in you `config/routes.rb`, add this line :

```
match '*url' => 'errors#routing'
```

Then create a controller called `ErrorsController` and add a `routing` action where you can use `params[:url]` to know which URL has caused the 404.

By the way, it is a good way to see if your website has dead links.

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 6):

Another way to handle routing (and all others) is to add the following in your ApplicationController:

```
unless Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local
  rescue_from Exception do |e|
    render_500 e
  end
  rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, with: :render_404
  rescue_from ActionController::UnknownController, with: :render_404
  rescue_from ActionController::UnknownAction, with: :render_404
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :render_404
end
```

Then make sure to define `render_500` and `render_404` so that they actually render something. In my app, I've done:

```
def render_404(exception)
  @not_found_path = exception.message
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render template: 'errors/error_404', layout: 'layouts/application', status: 404 }
    format.all { render nothing: true, status: 404 }
  end
end
```

And then created a template in `errors/error_404`. That way it handles all routing errors and still uses my application layout.

You can use @not_found_path to show the error to the user.

Comment: I used this method to catch "RecordNotFound" exceptions. Thank you.